# My app stopped every time when I load it

Tags: java, android, random

EDIT *Happy New Year!* To be precise ,I created a simple music app in Android Studio who read mp3 files from my internal storage. All good until I decide to put one random image on every single track on the list. (In front of the name of the song I want to appear one image).When I select one single image in 'src' at ImageView ,it works and appear to all songs. I will atach a part of my code below: Main Activity:

```
package com.alg.amzar.spectrum;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Random;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

static {
    System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
}
private ArrayList<Song> songList;
private ListView songView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    schimbare();

    songView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.song_list);
    songList = new ArrayList<Song>();

    getSongList();

    Collections.sort(songList, new Comparator<Song>(){
        public int compare(Song a, Song b){
            return a.getTitle().compareTo(b.getTitle());
        }
    });

    SongAdapter songAdt = new SongAdapter(this, songList);
    songView.setAdapter(songAdt);


}

public void schimbare() {
    int[] photos={R.drawable.img_0, R.drawable.img_1,R.drawable.img_2};

    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagine);

    Random ran=new Random();
    int i=ran.nextInt(photos.length);
    image.setImageResource(photos[i]);
}

public void getSongList() {
    ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();
    Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);

    if(musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()){
        //get columns
        int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        //add songs to list
        do {
            long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
            String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
            songList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle));
        }
        while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
    }
}

public native String stringFromJNI();
}
```

Activity Main .xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#FF330000"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/song_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Song.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:onClick="songPicked"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/imagine"
    android:layout_height="50dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/song_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF99"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-42dp"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Beside this ,I've 2 more java classes. I think the problem is here ,but idk what is wrong:

```
public void schimbare() {
    int[] photos={R.drawable.img_0, R.drawable.img_1,R.drawable.img_2};

    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagine);

    Random ran=new Random();
    int i=ran.nextInt(photos.length);
    image.setImageResource(photos[i]);
}
```

Another wondering of mine is what 'deprecated' means when is I use .getDrawable.
Thanks in advance!

Logcat:

```
ime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: com.alg.amzar.spectrum, PID: 28677
                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.alg.amzar.spectrum/com.alg.amzar.spectrum.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2381)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2433)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1346)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5341)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:830)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:646)
                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                        at com.alg.amzar.spectrum.MainActivity.schimbare(MainActivity.java:57)
                                                                        at com.alg.amzar.spectrum.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343)
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2335)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2433) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1346) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5341) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:830) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:646) 
                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My phone android version: 4.4.2 (API 19)
Target SDK Version:"19"
MinSDK Version:"14"

SongAdapter.java:

```
package com.alg.amzar.spectrum;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;



public class SongAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<Song> songs;
private LayoutInflater songInf;

public SongAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Song> theSongs) {
    songs = theSongs;
    songInf = LayoutInflater.from(c);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return songs.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //map to song layout
    LinearLayout songLay = (LinearLayout)songInf.inflate
            (R.layout.song, parent, false);
    //get title and artist views
    TextView songView = (TextView)songLay.findViewById(R.id.song_title);
    //get song using position
    Song currSong = songs.get(position);
    //get title and artist strings
    songView.setText(currSong.getTitle());
    //set position as tag
    songLay.setTag(position);
    return songLay;
}

}
```

Comment: Please also give android version of your phone you're testing with and targeted version of your application

Comment: you should debug your app, go line by line and see where is problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, `findViewById(R.id.imagine)` returns NULL because it doesn't exist in the layout 'activity_main', which you provided in `setContentView()`. `findViewById()` returns NULL if the view doesn't exist in current layout. R.id.imagine exists in the layout song.xml.

I think, you are trying to inflate the ListView with layout 'song'. Only after inflating you can call `findViewById` and `setImageResource`. You can done it in class SongAdapter, for each elements in ListView after inflating them.

Another suggestion, instead of using random images you can get album art of a song from MediaMetadataRetriever class. You can refer android documentation for that. But you have to solve this exception before.

Comment/ Delete function `schimbare()` in onCreate and edit SongAdapter like following.

```
package com.alg.amzar.spectrum;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;



public class SongAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<Song> songs;
private LayoutInflater songInf;

int[] photos={R.drawable.img_0, R.drawable.img_1,R.drawable.img_2};
Random ran=new Random();
// CHECK THIS:
public SongAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Song> theSongs) {
    songs = theSongs;
    // CHECK THIS:
    songInf =  ( LayoutInflater )c.
                 getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return songs.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //map to song layout
    LinearLayout songLay = (LinearLayout)songInf.inflate
            (R.layout.song, null);
    //get title and artist views
    TextView songView = (TextView)songLay.findViewById(R.id.song_title);
    // CHECK THIS:
    ImageView img = (ImageView)songLay.findViewById(R.id.imagine);
    //get song using position
    Song currSong = songs.get(position);
    //get title and artist strings
    songView.setText(currSong.getTitle());
    // CHECK THIS:
    int i=ran.nextInt(photos.length);
    img.setImageResource(photos[i]);
    //set position as tag
    songLay.setTag(position);
    return songLay;
}

}
```

Comment: I can't understant properly what to do in this case. First ,I wanted to do with MediaMetadatRetriever ,but this seems a bit complicated for me

Comment: You have to call `setImageResourse` in SongAdapter class. I'll provide you a link:[link](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-listview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html). Please try that.

Comment: You have to fix the current exception, before trying MediaMetadataRetriever. It's not a fix to the current exception.

Comment: I tried to follow this link defining a new variable in SongAdapter class which i use in my random function ,but still the same error ,app stopped working. I added the SongAdapter.java without the modification

Comment: Please find CHECK THIS tags, also comment schimbare() in onCreate.

Comment: I defined Context context = this; in SongAdapter.java because i got the "cannot find symbol context" After compiling ,I received the following error:   Error:(23, 23) error: incompatible types: SongAdapter cannot be converted to Context
Error:(51, 53) error: no suitable method found for inflate(int,ViewGroup,<null>)
method LayoutInflater.inflate(int,ViewGroup,boolean) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <null> cannot be converted to boolean)
method LayoutInflater.inflate(XmlPullParser,ViewGroup,boolean) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to XmlPullParser)

Comment: Sorry for the errors. I edited it in notepad, so can't figure out errors. Please see the changes. Context is c, which is the activity context passed from MainActivity. Also see the inflate method. Hope this will work.

Comment: I made it finally. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Deprecated mean that google no longer support this method, they telling you there is NEWER method you should use. the deprecated method is working fine FOR NOW. But some day (maybe tomorrow maybe 3 years from today) it will no longer work.

about the error, upload the log please.

The error is at line 57:

```html
                                                                        at com.alg.amzar.spectrum.MainActivity.schimbare(MainActivity.java:57)
```

I am not sure where line 57 is but you can check it in your code, if you still cant find the cause then update us which line is 57

```html
public void schimbare() {
    int[] photos={R.drawable.img_0, R.drawable.img_1,R.drawable.img_2};

    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagine);

    Random ran=new Random();

    // CHANGE photos.length to photos.length-1
    int i=ran.nextInt(photos.length);

    //ADD this 2 line of code below, then you can check in your Log if the problem is with the view (the view is null), or if the photos position is null.

    Log.d("bug_tag",String.valueOf(photos[i]));
   Log.d("bug_tag",String.valueOf(image.getId()));


    image.setImageResource(photos[i]);
}
```

Comment: I added the log

Comment: I still can't ffigure it out.The problem is where I thought initially. Line 57:    image.setImageResource(photos[i]);